# Make signature Full Name read-only, but allow editing of initials and font style

Tags: docusignapi

For an (accountless) recipient signer, on the screen where they set their signature, is it possible to make their signature Full Name read-only, but allow them to edit their initials and signature font style?

I'm using the DocuSign REST API to send out documents to be signed.  I've found that I can lock down their Full Name, by specifiying the signatureInfo node of the signer, but I can't get it to work without also specifying the initials and font style.  (To make matters worse, the only font that DocuSign will accept is "Mistral"; both "7_DocuSign" and "Rage Italic" fail with Bad Request).

```
{
    "emailSubject" : "Please Sign This",
    "status" : "sent",
    "documents" : [{
            "documentId" : "2444",
            "name" : "Please Sign This.pdf",
        }
    ],
    "recipients" : {
        "signers" : [{
                "recipientId" : 999999,
                "email" : "johndoe@example.com",
                "name" : "John Doe",
                "tabs" : { (omitted) },
                "clientUserId" : "GA4BH_Agent480",
                "routingOrder" : 1,
                "signatureInfo" : {
                    "fontStyle" : "Mistral",
                    "signatureInitials" : "JD",
                    "signatureName" : "John Doe"
                }
            }, {
                "recipientId" : 43255,
                "email" : "janedoe@example.com",
                "name" : "Jane Doe",
                "tabs" : { (omitted) },
                "clientUserId" : "GA4BH_Resident43255",
                "routingOrder" : 2,
                "signatureInfo" : {
                    "fontStyle" : "Mistral",
                    "signatureInitials" : "JD",
                    "signatureName" : "Jane Doe"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that Initials will always be automatically derived from Full Name, so I wouldn't expect it to be possible to lock Full Name while allowing edits to Initials.

Regardless of whether or not you lock Full Name, and/or specify a default Font style for the Signature, the signer should still have the option of clicking the "Change Style" link in the **Adopt Your Signature** dialog to select the font style they want to use for their signature.

For example, if my Create Envelope (***from Template***) request specifies the following Recipient info:

```
"recipients": {
    "signers" : [{
        "email": "adamsemail@outlook.com",
        "name": "Adam Adamson",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "roleName": "signer",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "signatureInfo":{
            "signatureName":"Adam Adamson",
            "fontStyle":"Mistral"
        }
     }]
}
```

Then this is what the recipient sees in the **Adopt Your Signature** dialog:

[image: DS Adopt]

Notice that I didn't have to specify **signatureInitials** in the API request, and that, for the recipient:

- Full Name is locked (as I specified in the API request).
- Initials are locked (derived automatically from full name).
- The recipient can click the **Change Style** link to choose a different font style.

**------- UPDATE:  DocuSign bug? -------**

Given the additional information you've provided (in comments and in your updated question), I am now able to repro your issue.  For some odd reason, whether or not the **signatureInitials** property is required and whether or not the **Change Style** link is clickable for the Signer seems to be dependent upon whether or not the recipient is specified as an embedded/captive signer (i.e., whether or not the **clientUserId** property is included in the request for the recipient).

If you ***omit*** the **clientUserId** property from the Create Envelope request (so that the recipient receives a "signing invitation" email from DocuSign):

- the **Change Style** link IS clickable for the signer in the
  "Adopt Your Signature" dialog
- initials are NOT required (i.e., no error if the **signatureInitials** property is not included in the Create Envelope request)

If you  ***include*** the **clientUserId** property in the Create Envelope request:

- the **Change Style** link is NOT clickable for the signer in
  the "Adopt Your Signature" dialog
- initials ARE required (i.e., error message "*Column 'InitialsText' does not allow nulls.*" occurs if the **signatureInitials** property is not included in the Create Envelope request)

I don't see any logical explanation of this behavior -- IMO, it should be consistent regardless of whether or not the recipient is embedded/captive.  Seems like perhaps you've discovered a DocuSign bug.

Comment: Thanks @KimBrandl.  That would be great; however, I run into two problems:

    1. If I remove signatureInitials, I get 'Bad Request' returned.

    2. The Change Style link doesn't open the list of fonts.  It does nothing.  (Tested in IE, Firefox & Chrome)

I'm testing this in https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/

Comment: I'm testing in demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2 as well, and am unable to repro the issue you describe. If you can update your question to include the full JSON Request (minus any documentBytes of course) that's giving you the "Bad Request" response, I might be able to help.

Comment: I've updated the question with the full JSON.  I haven't included the tabs, because there are so many.  (I'm using SignHere, InitialHere and FullName tabs among others).  I could add a few select ones if you want.  Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer with more info.  Unfortunately I can't explain the rational behind behavior you're seeing -- seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks again Kim.  Can anyone from DocuSign comment?  Is this a bug?  @Ergin?